# Cannot assign to 'Loginbutton_TouchUpInside' because it is a 'method group

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I've been trying to figure out the error of my ways but neither I, Google nor MSDN will can figure it out.
It would probably be easy enough if I knew exactly what I was looking for but been trying everything I've come over. At this point I am reaching out to all the guru's out there for a straight answer.
I'm running Xamarin on Visual Studio 2019, building an iOS app. Enough backstory, let's introduce the problem:

```cs
public partial class LoginViewController : UIViewController
{
    public LoginViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        Loginbutton_TouchUpInside += Loginbutton_TouchUpInside;
    }

    private void Loginbutton_TouchUpInside(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DatabaseReference reference = Database.DefaultInstance.GetRootReference().GetChild("Login");
        reference.SetValue<NSString>((NSString)"Connection is Successful");
    }

}
```

My issue is with this line:

```
Loginbutton_TouchUpInside += Loginbutton_TouchUpInside;
```

Thanks in advance
Didrik

Comment: Is `Loginbutton_TouchUpInside` your button name? If so you need to handle the event for example: `Loginbutton_TouchUpInside.TouchUpInside += ...` TBH, your element names need better defined, don't name them the same as routine...

Comment: What is this `Loginbutton_TouchUpInside` ?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ My button name is Loginbutton

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19772519/cannot-assign-because-it-is-a-method-group-c

Comment: `Loginbutton.TouchUpInside += Loginbutton_TouchUpInside` should work then. As I mentioned in my first comment, you need to handle `TouchUpInside` event of the button itself; at that time I didn't have your button name...

Comment: @DidrikHavasgaard If answer be helpful , rememeber to mark it later when have time ! Happy New Year :)

Answer (score 0):

> My issue is with this line:
>   `Loginbutton_TouchUpInside += Loginbutton_TouchUpInside;`

The error as already mentioned is correct:

```
 "Cannot assign to 'Loginbutton_TouchUpInside' because it is a 'method group"
```

You are trying to assign a method to a method, not possible. What you are wanting to do is handle the `TouchUpInside` event. In order to do so, you need to assign that button's event to the new method.

```
 Loginbutton.TouchUpInside += Loginbutton_TouchUpInside
```

Now when the button is tapped, it will be handled by the `Loginbutton_TouchUpInside` method/routine.

Comment: Ahhhhhh, I see the error or my ways! Thank you good person! Merry Xmas! :)